# How to set main class from submodule to root in sbt

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I have multimodule setup, where **root** is just a project wrapper for submodules **core** and **util**.
**Core** is actually the application and contains main class(extending App) which I want to run.
Staying at project **root**(wrapper) I want to run `sbt run` and execute the main method from **core** submodule

```
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .aggregate(util, core)
  .settings(
    mainClass in Compile := (mainClass in Compile in core).value
  )

lazy val util = project
  .in(file("util"))

lazy val core = project
  .in(file("core"))
  .settings(
    mainClass in Compile := Some("com.iwaneez.scala.Hello"),
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies
  )
  .dependsOn(util)
```

I expect to run the application just by executing `sbt run`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addCommandAlias` can be used to replace `run` in the `root` project.

```
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .aggregate(util, core)
  .settings(
    addCommandAlias("run", "core/run")
  )
```

```
sbt:root> run --test
[info] Running com.iwaneez.scala.Hello --test
Hello List(--test)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following command will let you run the project

```
  sbt "project core" run
```

Comment: Yeah, but is it possible to setup build to run it by only using sbt run?

Comment: This also means I can remove all main class settings in the root wrapper?

Comment: @Iwaneez No, it is not possible to do. Because it will not be able to detect main from the root.